# adjust responsive size of iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Hello I'm trying to adjust the size of youtube videos in my web. I want them to be responsive that I'm using jquery to do that. I have done it successfully but the thing is I want the height of youtube video to be decreased. Right now, it's too big. When I try to do it, the responsiveness feature is removed. Can you check how I can decrease the size of the video and keep the responsiveness?

```
<script>
function update_iframe_size(){
  var parent_id = $("iframe").parent().attr("id");
  if (parent_id == "main_video") {
    var parent_class = $("iframe").parent().attr("class");
    var parent_width = $("iframe").parent().width();
    console.log(parent_class);
    var width = $("iframe").css("width"); // $("iframe").width();
    var height = $("iframe").css("height");
    var ratio = parseInt(height)/parseInt(width);
    var new_height = parseInt(parent_width) * ratio
    $("iframe").css("width", parent_width);
    $("iframe").css("height", new_height);
  }
}
update_iframe_size()
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
  // alert("reized");
  update_iframe_size();
});
</script>
```

I tried to decrease the height that I did `$("iframe").css("height", new_height*0.7);`
 but then the height is set to the one I want. However responsiveness gets messed up.

Comment: Why don't you use `css class` for this: `width : 100%; height : 100%` ?

Comment: then responsiveness gets messed up

Comment: Working demo would clarify your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Refer following link: iFrame always take height and width 100% depends on parent div/element which is position relative.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/masau/7wrhm/

Comment: yeah I saw that, that's the first thing that coems out when I typed iframe javascript.

Comment: May I know what you want so I will help you.